# How to automatically convert from org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to Pojo using Jackson in a Spring Boot Camel Kotlin application

Tags: kotlin, apache-camel, spring-camel

In a Spring Boot 2.7. Camel 3.20.x project written in Kotlin I have a REST endpoint that receives a JSON payload. I've added the Camel Jackson dependency to deal with JSON<->POJO transformation:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
data class Payment(val iban: String, val amount: Float)
```

```
    rest("/payments")
            .post("/")
            .to("direct:processPayment")

    from("direct:processPayment")
            .log("Body \${body}")
            .log("Body \${body.getClass()}")
```

These are the logs of the route:

```
Body {"payment":{"iban":"ABCD","amount":150.0}}
Body class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
```

As you can see the body is correctly displayed as String, however, the type is `InputStreamCache` instead of my Payment DTO.

I updated the route to unmarshall the body to the Payment DTO:

```
    from("direct:processPayment")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Payment::class.java)
        .log("Body \${body}")
        .log("Body \${body.getClass()}")
```

This fails with:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `xxx.Payment` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Why isn't the conversion working?

Comment: Can you show your Payment class ? Is there a default constructor (**without** argument) ?

Comment: Otherwise, try to introduce a `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` **BEFORE** the unmarshalling

Comment: @TacheDeChoco nope, it doesn't have a default constructor, I'm using a Kotlin Data class

Comment: Your pojo needs to respect the Java Bean conventions (eg with default constructor) otherwise the unmarshalling cannot work

Comment: It makes sense, I verified it worked with a default constructor, if you add it as answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encountered error has nothing to see with Camel nor Spring, but is directly related to Jackson.

As the error message indicates it, the reason is that the `Payment` pojo does not satisfy the requirement of having a default (**parameterless**) constructor.

Comment: Actually it’s about JSON (Jackson, not JAXB), but you’re right about the default empty constructor requirement

Comment: Yes of course :-/ I have just corrected

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was correctly described in the accepted answer. However there's a Kotlin compatible solution that allows the use of data classes without default (empty) constructors.

1. Add jackson-module-kotlin dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

2. With this, Spring Boot will tweak its own Jackson ObjectMapper. Now, just tell Camel to use that Spring configured object mapper:

```
camel:
  dataformat:
    jackson:
      auto-discover-object-mapper: true
```